# list index error while converting json using python

Tags: python

i have  written this query and its mainly  getting the details of json .but i am getting an error

```
print("Latitude\longitude\Title\Place\Mag")

while i< (len(dict_data)):

    print(str(dict_data['features'][i]['geometry']['coordinates'][i]) +"\t"+
      str(dict_data['features'][i]['geometry']['coordinates'][i+1])+ "\t"+
     str(dict_data['features'][i]['properties']['title']) +"\t"+ str(dict_data['features'][i]['properties']['place'])
     +"\t"+ str(dict_data['features'][i]['properties']['mag']))

    i=i+1
```

### error is coming as

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Apparently one of your indices is out of bounds. Have you done any debugging? Also, show sample data.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and the links it contains....https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#IndexError

Comment: Maybe [i+1] is a mistake but I have no way of knowing. You definatlty should have included a json example.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are looking for longitude and latitude, I am guessing that the `i+1` is wrong as suggested by @Hadus.  Also, some of the lookups can be moved out of the print to make is cleaner:

```
LONGITUDE=0
LATTITUDE=1
while i< (len(dict_data)):
    coords = dict_data['features'][i]['geometry']['coordinates']
    properties = dict_data['features'][i]['properties']
    print(
        str(coords[LONGITUDE]) +"\t"+ str(coords[LATITUDE])+ "\t"+
        str(properties['title']) +"\t"+ str(properties['place']) +"\t"+
        str(properties['mag']))

i=i+1
```

Answer (score 0):

In loop statement

```
while i< (len(dict_data))
```

you comparing `i` with length of `dict_data` dictionary. But in `print` statement you use `i` to index `dict_data['features']` field and (!) `dict_data['features'][i]['geometry']['coordinates']` field. Also, you using `i+1` index. I need more information (json example at least) to say for sure what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The coordinates are a list (of length 2) not a dictionary.

Example:
`{'features':{0:{'geometry':{'coordinates':['latitude', 'longtitude']}}}}`

```
    print(str(dict_data['features'][i]['geometry']['coordinates'][0]) +"\t"+
  str(dict_data['features'][i]['geometry']['coordinates'][1])+ "\t"+
 str(dict_data['features'][i]['properties']['title']) +"\t"+ str(dict_data['features'][i]['properties']['place'])
 +"\t"+ str(dict_data['features'][i]['properties']['mag']))
```

@Andrew Gillis 's answer is better and I would recommend it unless you want ugly code what is never good.